# error Parsing error: Unexpected character '#' in md file

Tags: eslint, git-husky

Everything was fine, until I added `lint-staged` using `husky`.

I got error related to `README.md`

```
packages\README.md
1:1  error  Parsing error: Unexpected character '#'

> 1 | # @folo/forms
  | ^
```

In `package.json`:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,md}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
```

**What I am missing? Why this only happening when I run `eslint` and doesn't throw error inside my `Atom` editor?**

Answer (score 7):

Here's my humble solution for this:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.{md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
```

I don't need to lint my `.md` files. Just run `prettier`.

Comment: It didn't work for me,